# Anhular 6 post method tod add a row in json

Tags: angular6

Can any one please help me to write angular 6 Http post method to add a data in JSON...I am able to get the datafrom the same json but while inserting I am getting an error that json not found .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGp1H.png)

Comment: do you need to send data in json format to a rest service or whatelse?

Comment: Yes I have json file... it contains some data i want to add one more row to the same...

Comment: the image is empty, post your code and the error you receive please